# How to change option width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys i have a simple drop down box which i have styled my self but i have no idea how to change the option width. So it looks like this : 
[image]

As you can tell the drop down is way smaller then the actual box so i was wondering how i can edit this size and get rid of the blue around the box and change its colour. I'm using boostrap 3

HTML:

```
<div class="styled-select">
   <select>
     <option>Here is the first option</option>
     <option>The second option</option>
     <option>The thrid option</option>
   </select>
  <span class="fa fa-sort-desc"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.styled-select {
      border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
      line-height: 20px;
    color: #555555;
    padding-left: 22px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
}

.styled-select option {
 width: 74%;
}
.styled-select, .styled-select select {
 width: 74%;
      display: inline-block;
}
select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.styled-select select {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .styled-select select {
    width: 110%;
  }
}

.fa-sort-desc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
} 

_:-o-prefocus,
.selector {
  .styled-select {
    background: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of styling a div containing your select object, you should style the select object itself, for instance:

```css
.styled-select {
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #555;
  padding-left: 22px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
}
.styled-select option {
  width: 74%;
}
.styled-select, .styled-select select {
  width: 74%;
  display: inline-block;
}
select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.styled-select select {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .styled-select select {
    width: 110%;
  }
}
.fa-sort-desc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
_:-o-prefocus .styled-select, .selector .styled-select {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="styled-select">
   <option>Here is the first option</option>
   <option>The second option</option>
   <option>The thrid option</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Answer edited - you were using SCSS - it needed to be converted.

Comment: Sorry 1 more thing , my height wont change now and I'm not sure why

Comment: @RonTheOld please confirm this answer helped you by accepting the answer.

Comment: @JaneDoe please relax , some people need to go eat sometimes

Comment: @RonTheOld I was very relaxed, just wanted to remind you.. Have a good day.